# Why does console.log not require an argument in this case?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

If I use the Fetch API as follows:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(console.log)
```

I understand that this would log the result of the previous "then" (the response data), but why does console.log not require any arguments in this case?

Is there any technical reasoning or documentation behind this, and can any other built-in methods be used in this nature?

Comment: Since `then` takes a callback with argument that is what is returned from the last then, the argument is passed to console.log. Basically `.then(function(json) { console.log(json) })` or `.then(json => console.log(json))`

Comment: It's the same as `.then(thing => console.log(thing))`, except you don't create an anonymous function and all of the arguments get passed for you. Any callable can be used like that.

Answer (score 4):

Thats simple Javascript, in this case the `console.log` requires that argument, what happens here is that the `then` function takes a callback as its first argument and internally executes that callback with the argument returned by the last `then` function. So it means that you are passing the reference (or a copy, im not sure) of `console.log` function instead of directly executing this.

In summary, this:

```
function a (callback) {
  var something = 12345;
  callback(something);
}

a(console.log);
```

is the same as

```
a(function(something) {
  console.log(something);
})
```